# How to use FIPS compliant encryption in a stateless web app roundtrip

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, encryption

I have this GridView that calls a crypto class to encrypt the record key.  My computer is a government computer so the FIPSAlgorithmPolicy is turned on.  This makes the original RijndaelManaged crypto class to fail.  I am replacing it with AesCryptoServiceProvider. However, I could not decrypt the string to original plain text value.  It says "The input data is not a complete block".  The code is from a sample code, but broke the code into two public methods to be called by web UI. One during PageLoad(), the other when any row in the grid is clicked, the encrypted record id is passed to the encryto class to be dcrtpted.  Thank you for your help.

```html
Registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\FIPSAlgorithmPolicy
```

```html
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Task">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="Hlink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "~/p_encounter.aspx?ref=tickler&mhid="+BEncrypt(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EVENT_ID").ToString()) %>'>
      <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "RowNum") %>
    </asp:HyperLink>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

```js
public string BEncrypt(string str) {
  return SimpleAES_FIPS_Compliant.EncryptToString(str);;
}
```

```js
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace CMT {
  public class SimpleAES_FIPS_Compliant {

    public static string EncryptToString(string plainText) {
      // Create a new instance of the AesCryptoServiceProvider
      // class.  This generates a new key and initialization 
      // vector (IV).
      using(AesCryptoServiceProvider myAes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider()) {
        // Encrypt the string to an array of bytes.
        byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(plainText, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);
        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encrypted);
      }
    }

    public static string DecryptString(string encryptedString) {
      using(AesCryptoServiceProvider myAes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider()) {
        char[] charArray = encryptedString.ToCharArray();
        var byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(charArray, 0, charArray.Length);
        // Decrypt the bytes to a string.
        return DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byteArray, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);
      }
    }

    public static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV) {
      // Check arguments.
      if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
      if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
      if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");
      byte[] encrypted;
      // Create an AesCryptoServiceProvider object
      // with the specified key and IV.
      using(AesCryptoServiceProvider aesAlg = new AesCryptoServiceProvider()) {
        aesAlg.Key = Key;
        aesAlg.IV = IV;

        // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

        // Create the streams used for encryption.
        using(MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream()) {
          using(CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)) {
            using(StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt)) {

              //Write all data to the stream.
              swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
            }
            encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
          }
        }
      }

      // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
      return encrypted;

    }

    public static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV) {
      // Check arguments.
      if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
      if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
      if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");

      // Declare the string used to hold the decrypted text.
      string decripted = string.Empty;

      // Create an AesCryptoServiceProvider object
      // with the specified key and IV.
      using(AesCryptoServiceProvider aesAlg = new AesCryptoServiceProvider()) {
        aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
        aesAlg.Key = Key;
        aesAlg.IV = IV;

        // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

        // Create the streams used for decryption.
        using(MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText)) {
          using(CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)) {
            using(StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt)) {

              // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
              // and place them in a string.
              decripted = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
            }
          }
        }

      }

      return decripted;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with just replacing the encryption algorithm from RijndalelManaged to AesCryptoServiceProvider.  All other code is unchanged.